# Trying to find error and fix. Python bulk renamer program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on this for a school assignment http://cit.dixie.edu/cs/1410/asst_bulkrename.html. I just finished coding and now can't figure out what I did wrong. When I run it from the command line using "python bulk.py sub iphone" "sub" being the folder with the images, and "iphone" being the prefix,I get this error:

```
linux@ubuntu:~/Documents$ python bulk.py sub iphone
Directory: ['sub']
Prefix: iphone
['pic 4', 'pic 5', 'red sky (another copy).jpg', 'pic 3', 'pic 8 ', 'red sky (copy).jpg', 'pic 7', 'pic 6', 'red sky.jpg', 'pic 1', 'pic 2', 'red sky (4th copy).jpg', 'red sky (3rd copy).jpg']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bulk.py", line 173, in <module>
main()
File "bulk.py", line 152, in main
inorder = sortByMTime(path, matching)
File "bulk.py", line 37, in sortByMTime
for file in matching:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I think iv'e been staring at code for too long and am completely missing something. Any help would be awesome.

```
import os
import sys
import random

directory = []
prefix = []
path = []




def filterByExtension(root, allfiles, extensions):
  matching = []
  ext = []
  for i in allfiles:
    name = i
    dot = name.rfind('.')
    ext = name[dot::].lower()
    if ext not in extensions:
      continue
    else:
      path = os.path.join(root, name)
      if not os.path.isfile(path):
        print "Error 404, file not found. Loading"
        print "blue screen of death in 10 seconds"
        print "unless mistake is corrected accordinly"
        continue
        matching.append(name)
    return matching





def sortByMTime(root, matching):
  presort = []
  for file in matching:
    path = os.path.join(root, file)
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(path)
    presort.append((mtime, file))
    presort.sort()
  print "Here is the presorted shtuff",presort
  return presort





def assignNames(prefix, inorder):
  count = ''
  digits = 0
  count = str(len(inorder))
  digits = len(count)
  template = '%%0%dd' % digits
  newnames = {}
  count = 0
  for i in inorder:
    count += 1
    s = template % count
    newnames[i[1]] = prefix+s+'.'+i[1].split('.')[1]
  print "Here are the new names that will be used",newnames
  return newnames





def makeTempName(allfiles):
  n = random.randant(1,1000000000)
  t = '__temp' + str(n) + '__'
  while t in allfiles:
    n+=1
    t = '__temp' + str(n) + '__'
  return t





def makeScript(inorder, newnames, tempname):
  script = []
  print
  print "a"
  print
  for elt in inorder:
    print
    print "b"
    print
    chain = []
    inthechain ={}
    if elt not in newnames:
      continue
    elif newnames[elt] == elt:
      del newnames[elt]
      continue
    elif newnames[elt] not in newnames:
      print "Script Output"
      script.append((elt,newnames[elt]))
      del newnames [elt]
      continue
    else:
      link = elt
      while True:
        target = newnames[elt]
        chain.append((link,target))
        inthechain[link] = True
        link = target
        if link not in newnames:
          break

    chain.reverse()
    for (a,b) in chain:
      script.append(a,b)
      del newnames[a]
  return script




def doRenames(path, script):
  for entry in script:
    print entry[0],'---->',entry[1]
  oldpath = os.path.join(path, entry[0])
  newpath = os.path.join(path, entry[1])
  if os.path.exists(newpath):
    print "Error 404, file name seems to alrady exist"
    sys.exit(1)
  os.rename(oldpath, newpath)





def main():

  if len(sys.argv) <= 1 or len(sys.argv) > 3:
    print "You have messed up, please check your arguments again"
    sys.exit(1)

  elif len(sys.argv) == 3:    
    directory = sys.argv[1]
    path = os.path.abspath(directory)
    dirname = os.path.basename(path)
    print "Directory: ", sys.argv[1:-1]
    print "Prefix: ", sys.argv[-1]
    allfiles = []
    allfiles = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])
    print allfiles
    extensions = []
    extensions = ['jpeg','jpg','png','gif']
    matching = filterByExtension(path, allfiles, extensions)
    inorder = sortByMTime(path, matching)
    newnames = assignNames(prefix, inorder)
    tempname = makeTempName(allfiles)
    script = makeScript(inorder, newnames, tempname)
    renamed = doRenames(path, script)

  else:
    directory = sys.argv[1]
    path = os.path.abspath(directory)
    dirname = os.path.basename(path)    
    print "Directory: ", path
    print "Prefix: ", dirname


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `filterByExtension`, `return matching` is inside the for-loop and so can be skipped (resulting in a return value of `None`) if `allfiles` is empty or each entry gets skipped with `continue`. Fix the indentation to remove this bug.

Comment: @ChrisSummerhays If this answered your question, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark. If you can't solve the other error you referred to on your own, open another question about it.